# Replace iso-8859-1 encoding symbols in python open module

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decode, iso-8859-1

How can i decode iso-8859-1 symbols within `open` funcion.

```
filename = open(f'/opt/PATH/{shorter}', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
file_content = filename.read()
filename.close()
```

which gave me `ÿ` (i guess this was comma):

```
[...]
11 Dir(s) 3ÿ016ÿ011ÿ776 bytes free
[...]
```

Comment: There's no such thing. That's the plain old Latin1 encoding, what people typically call ASCII even though it's not. If you get unexpected text it's because you used the wrong encoding to read that file. What happens if you *don't* specify an encoding? How was that file produced?

Comment: A comma is part of the 0-127 ASCII range that's identical in all codepages. If you get `ÿ` it means the character was definitely *not* a comma. It may have been another character that looks like a comma in the original codepage, eg a typographer's comma.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a space? The byte 0xFF is a non-breaking space in Extended ASCII `ÿ` in Latin 1 and a dot in other codepages

Comment: When i do not specify encoding i get ```'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 703: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: Which python version are you using? The default encoding now is UTF8, not `ascii`. Not that it matters - `0xFF` isn't valid in UTF8. Your file is *definitely* not ISO-8869-1 though. You need to find what codepage was used. Quite likely, it matches the *country* where the machine runs. Perhaps it's 8859-2 which is used in Poland

Comment: Was this file creating from the output of a dir/ls command in a fancy shell that uses non-breaking spaces to display well-formatted text?

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `print('3ÿ016ÿ011ÿ776 bytes'.encode( 'iso-8859-1').decode( 'cp852'))` -> `3 016 011 776 bytes` and vise versa: `print('3 016 011 776 bytes'.encode( 'cp852').decode( 'iso-8859-1'))` -> `3ÿ016ÿ011ÿ776 bytes`. Use `open(f'/opt/PATH/{shorter}', 'r', encoding='cp852')` (or `cp437` / `cp850` /  `cp775` / … or whatever you get from `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v OEMCP|find "OEMCP"`.

Comment: @JosefZ why do that instead of actually finding the correct codepage and using it? Since the OP is Polish, and the text seems to come from Windows, `iso-8859-2`  or `windows-1250` would be the most likely codepage. 852 would be used only if someone explicitly configured the OS to use a DOS codepage instead of the Windows codepage.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, you are wrong. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72124893/3439404) with detailed explanation of this particular [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case origin…

Comment: its definitely iso-8859-1 ```[user@server LOG]$ file -i SA1012``` gives```SA1012: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
``` ill try mojibake solution and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

### `cmd`

```
>NUL chcp 852
>dir_cp852.txt dir /C
type dir_cp852.txt | find /I "bytes free"
```

> ```
>               28 Dir(s)  832 467 206 144 bytes free
> ```

```
>NUL chcp 1252
type dir_cp852.txt | find /I "bytes free"
```

> ```
>               28 Dir(s)  832ÿ467ÿ206ÿ144 bytes free
> ```

### Python

```
with open('dir_cp852.txt', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as filename:
    file_content = filename.read()

print(file_content[-52:])
```

> ```
>               28 Dir(s)  832ÿ467ÿ206ÿ144 bytes free
> ```

**Solution:**

```
with open('dir_cp852.txt', 'r', encoding='cp852') as filename:
    file_content = filename.read()

print(file_content[-52:])
```

> ```
>               28 Dir(s)  832 467 206 144 bytes free
> ```

**Note** `file_content[-52:]` (in Python prompt):

```
'              28 Dir(s)  832\xa0467\xa0206\xa0144 bytes free\n'
```

shows character in  *mojibake*: `\xa0`   (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*) with code `0xFF` in [Code page 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852) (and more *MS-DOS* code pages).

---

Please note the `/C` switch in `dir /C` above (*Display the thousand separator in file sizes*).; I have overridden the default by (globally defined) `set "DIRCMD=/-C"`.

The thousand separator in file sizes is defined in `Control Panel\Clock and Region` -> <kbd>Region</kbd>:
`reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sThousand`

Comment: simply changing ```encoding='iso-8859-1'``` to ```encoding='cp852'``` solved issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) instead:

```
filename = open(f'/opt/PATH/{shorter}', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-2')
```

You can also try `cp1250` or `windows-1250`. The [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) codepage is slightly different from ISO-8859-2.

`ascii` refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage. That codepage wouldn't be able to open your file either.

If you used `dir` in a `cmd` shell, use `chcp 65001` to switch to UTF8 before executing the script. Or use Powershell Core instead.

**Codepages**

As I explained in the comments, `ÿ` isn't some kind of encoding symbol. Single-byte codepages like Latin1 (aka ISO-8859-1), Central/Eastern European codepages like ISO-8859-2, Cyrillic etc simply encode characters to single byte values. Encoding symbols appear only in Unicode and markup languages like HTML and XML.

The character you posted `ÿ` is encoded to 255 (0xFF) in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). In the old IBM DOS codepages [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or [852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852) that byte corresponds to a non-breaking space. In the other ISO-8859- codepages including the Eastern European [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) the value is used for a dot.

**What happened**

I suspect the file was created by redirecting the `dir` output on Windows' `cmd` shell. `dir` in Powershell doesn't have this footer. `dir` in `cmd` will use the user's (yours) locale to format dates and numbers. This means you could get different results if someone used a custom format. Linux shells also allow such localization and customization.

The `cmd` shell is *non*-Unicode though, so when you redirected the output the shell used the current codepage, which matches the user's locale, to encode the byte values. To use UTF8 you have to explicitly change the shell codepage with

```
chcp 65001
```

**Better alternatives**

Windows Terminal and Powershell use Unicode by default like Windows itself and don't have such problems. Redirecting even allows you to specify encodings, handle results as objects or tables and even output the data as CSV or HTML. `cmd` is essentially a legacy shell.

In Powershell/Powershell Core you could use :

```
Dir | Export-CSV C:\Users\username\Desktop\FileList.csv
```

To export the directory list to a properly formatted CSV file in UTF8

Comment: The default value for the `encoding` parameter of `open()` isn't UTF-8 – [it depends on the environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). It *happens* to be UTF-8 on many modern systems, but it doesn't depend on the Python version. (The same environment-depending default is used for `print()` and `sys.stdin` etc.)

Comment: @lenz you're right, I always get confused by this.

Comment: @lenz in the comments though the OP says that omitting the encoding defaults to `ascii` which is certainly not expected.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely wrong. Code `0xFF` (decimal 255) in  [`iso-8859-2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) is `˙` (U+02D9,  *Dot Above*) [grin].

Comment: @JosefZ by the time you posted this comment I had changed the answer and links for 3 hours. You say what I also say